# Error when trying to deploy signal-twilio-video-webrtc-go-demo

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to deploy a simple video chat as part of our website customer support. The sample code has been a big help and so far I have successfully built and deployed both of these:

twilio/twilio-video-app-react

twilio/twilio-video-diagnostics-react-app

The instructions for both of those were clear and I had no problem deploying them to the serverless service.

However, the react app has more features than we need, so I was hoping to try a smaller, simpler sample web application from here:

philnash/signal-twilio-video-webrtc-go-demo

My problem/question is that when I follow those instructions and get to:

npm run deploy

all I get is an error message:

> signal-twilio-videe-webrtc-go@0.0.0 predeploy

> build

**sh: build: command not found**

Can anyone explain what that means and how I can get past that error?

Comment: After Googling for a while and lots of trial-and-error I figured out that by changing one line in the package.json file I could get the code deployed.

Changing one of the "scripts" lines from this:

"predeploy": "build",

changed to this:

"predeploy": "npm run build",

I have no idea what this means or how to explain it, but I hope this information helps someone.

Feel free to provide an explanation if you have any information about this.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist and creator of that demo here.

Apologies for getting the `predeploy` script wrong, I thought I knew what I was doing.

I have now updated the `predeploy` script to `npm run build` as you suggested in your comment.

As for why this was a problem, I believe that I was under the misconception that one npm script could refer to another without the `npm run` prefix. However, it cannot. So, to run one npm script from another, as in this `predeploy` script, I needed to refer to the script as `npm run build`. I am referring to another script like this because the [`predeploy` script is automatically run by npm before the `deploy` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) (you can do this with any script you create, and you can run scripts after using the `post` prefix too).

[I have updated the repo](https://github.com/philnash/signal-twilio-video-webrtc-go-demo) with this, as well as some dependency updates, so hopefully this doesn't cause further problems.